# Degree of Map between Pseudomanifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, soft-question, differential-topology

There are two different ways to define a degree of map.

- Let $M$, $N$ be smooth, and $M$ is compact, $N$ is connected. If $f\in C(M,N)$, we define $\deg f$ by smooth approximation. [*Milnor/Topology from a Differential Viewpoint*]
- Let $M$, $N$ be finite pseudomanifold, and $f\in C(M,N)$, $\deg f$ can be defined by simplical approximation. [*Spanier/Algebra Topology/Page 207*]

In the second, both spaces are compact, so it is smaller than the first one from this point. So my question is

> Can we remove the finiteness of $N$ in the second definition?

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

---

This is a question, same to
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016166/degree-of-map-between-pseudomanifold. However there is not an answer. So I move it to Mathoverflow, and ask for some help. Thank you.

Comment: I bet there are way more than two different ways to define the degree of a map! What about homology? (Maybe Borel-Moore homology in the noncompact case?)

Comment: I think you can define the degree to be as in Exercise F.1 on Spanier page 207 (which is entirely analogous to how Milnor does it in the smooth case). The point is your pseudo manifold doesn't have to be finite to have an orientation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan En, thank you for the idea of BM homology. But I'm not very familiar with the sheaf theory. Is there any     combinatorial way to understand?

Comment: @MarkGrant Actually, the second definition is from the Exercise F.1, which you have pointed out. So if I remove the finiteness, is the definition well-defined?

Comment: @gaoxinge: I don't see why not. If $M$ is compact, then the inverse image of any simplex in $N$ under a simplicial map will be a finite union of simplices. So as long as $M$ and $N$ are oriented, we get a finite sum of $+1$s and $-1$s.

Comment: @MarkGrant En, yes. But if we choose different oriented $n$-simplexes in $N$ or different simplical approximations to $f$, will the $\deg$ be same?

Comment: I presume that you can prove well-definedness in the same way as in the smooth case (by showing that it's homotopy invariant and that any $n$-simplex is mapped onto any other $n$-simplex by a homeomorphism isotopic to the identity) but I haven't time to check the details. By the way, if $N$ is not compact then the degree will be zero (since $f(M)$ is compact so $f$ is not surjective). Milnor notes this on p.20).

Comment: @MarkGrant Oh, yes. When $N$ is infinite, $\deg f$ must be zero. Thank you.